# Need to find a branch with out going into the vobs

Tags: java, jenkins, clearcase

Hey every one is there any way that I can find a branch without in the `Vob directory` For example:

```
Cleartool find lstype -kind brtype | grep branch name
```

We can find only we are in the Vob directory or else it throws me an error:

> "unable to determine vob for pathname"

So any one help me in this finding branch command without going into `Vob directory`

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly: you need to have the vob in which the brtype has been defined.

That means you don't have to go to (`cd`) a vob directory.

But you need to add to your command the anme of the vob tag, using [`cleartool lstype`](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_lstype.htm?cp=SSSH27_8.0.0%2F9-1-2-1-6):

```
cleartool lstype -kind brtype -invob /avobtag
```

Note that "`cleartool find lstype`" would *not* work anyway (vob tag or not)

[`cleartool find`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_7.1.2/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_find.htm?cp=SSSH27_7.1.2%2F8-0-0-1-14) needs a "pname", that is a file or directory element, which involves being within a `view/vobtag`.
But you can use cleartool lstype *without* having to use a view.
Not "`cleartool find lstype`": the combination of the two command would not make sense.

Comment: Hi guys with the clear tool lstype  -kind brtype -invob /vobtag giving me all the branches in that vob so here I need to find a specific branch name by giving its name like.     Cleartool lstype -kind brtype(developingxxx) -invob/vobtag it giving me the error saying that unknown type is their any way to search only one branch that I need which is already exists

Comment: @Madhumitha sure: do a grep on the output: `cleartool lstype -kind brtype -invob /avobtag|grep -i abranchname`

Comment: Awesome thank you so much I appreciate your help I know this questions are silly but am just learning it thanks though for your help and time

Comment: @Madhumitha no problem: don't forget http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer for this answer and the previous ones.